# Find useful information about device on VLAN

Tags: networking, dvr, iot

So here's my situation:

I work for a company with 600+ locations that are all over the US.  I work at the central office and all the locations are connected on a single VLAN.  I'm responsible for managing a networked video recorder at each location, because of our network topography I can access each device with a web browser pointed at their LAN address, for example 10.0.3.4 even though the device is not "public facing", it appears like a local device to me in the central office.

The challenge I'm having is these NVR boxes are made by a wide variety of brands, we've been pretty good about consistently using the same products, but since 3/4 of our locations are acquisitions that had existing infrastructure we took over, I have to work with devices from a lot of different manufacturers.  There's often situations where all the information I have about a device is its IPv4 address and a webpage that loads in the browser when I go there.  **I'm looking for techniques to find out more information about a device.**  Oftentimes they are still configured with default credentials so if I can find out the model or even manufacturer, I can get in and reconfigure the box properly.  There are also times where I find that the device is not going to be fixable and I should ship out a replacement, or that the device isn't what I expected and I need to check other addresses on the subnet.

Here's things I've already tried:

1. Physical access - often not useful, either because the staff onhand is incompetent or because the box is concealed in an unknown location.
2. MAC address - sometimes useful, sometimes... not so much.
3. Information on the webpage that loads, either on the page itself or in the page source.
4. Telnet backdoors/hard-coded credentials.  I know this is a huge problem with DVRs but in my case its been a little helpful.  Unfortunately (probably fortunately, actually) very few of these devices on our network actually have this well-known bug, and the ones that do I've already accessed.

I appreciate any creative insights and ideas you can give me.

Comment: You could try using a tool like nmap to do a port scan and OS fingerprinting. Also, since you know the IP, and you're on the same VLAN, you can look up its MAC address, then figure out which switch port it's on (you do have manageable switches, don't you?) and sniff traffic on that port to see what kind of traffic it's sending. Togging the link down for a few seconds then back up while running a sniffer may catch more interesting traffic, as many boxes do extra initialization & discovery work when the link first comes up.

Comment: We do have managed switches, but they aren't _manageable_, it's a PCI thing, basically there's an approved template for how each location is set up based on what type of store it is, and I cannot make changes to it, so toggling the port off and on is not an option.

Comment: The first three bytes of the MAC address describe the manufacturer of the LAN card, which can be extremely helpful (unless your VLAN mangles the MAC address for some reason). Next, if you have a Linux box somewhere, run `nmap` on it - it does OS fingerprinting and shows open ports, which can be extremely helpful in determining the NVR brand.